# Need cast something as a type parameter in method

Tags: c#, types

I need to be able to determine if the item that I'm getting out of my cache can be cast to the type of an object that I am passing into my method so that I can remove the item from the cache in the event that the item is not a valid instance of that type.

Below is my failed attempts:

```
 Get(dataCache, "cachedItemLabel", myObject);

 public static object Get(DataCache dataCache, string label, object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                //return  (obj)dataCache.Get(label);
                //return  typeof(obj)dataCache.Get(label);
                //return  dataCache.Get(label) as typeof(obj);

            }
            catch (DataCacheException)
            {
                dataCache.Remove(label);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

The code above results in the following exceptions:

`return  dataCache.Get(label) as typeof(obj);` result in "Type expected"

`return  typeof(obj)dataCache.Get(label);` results in " ; expected"

`return (obj)dataCache.Get(label);` results in "The type or namespace name 'obj' could not be found"

Comment: I'm assuming you get a runtime exception.  Can you post the exception in your question?

Comment: You're just casting whatever it is right back to object, so what would be the point, even if you could do it?

Comment: you have to use generics.

Comment: @TrevorElliott it won't compile, so unfortunately no exception to post.

Comment: Surely your compiler told you obj wasn't a valid type??

Comment: @Servy the point is the catch clause, as I am fighting some issues with type mismatches on Azure caching.

Comment: Look up the difference between `GetType` and `typeof`. You seem to be confused about how to get the type of `obj`. And generics, as Daniel suggested, might be what you're really looking for.

Comment: @JeffBorden Your `catch` clause wouldn't catch any errors related to the improper type existing in the cache.  Do you want it to?  If so, you should make that clear in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.  Clearly I'm confused and am asking for help, so I appreciate the negative response to my request for help.  @TimS. yea I tried something like  return  (obj.GetType())dataCache.Get(label); but it still doesn't worky.

Comment: @Liam right, I am basically trying to replace  return dataCache.Get(label) as myObject;  with a generic way of casting it and catching the caching mismatch errors.

Comment: @JeffBorden I didn't downvote, but you clearly have compiler errors that your haven't posted.  Instead of posting what the compiler errors were, you merely told us that you "can't quite get the code to work".  Posting the actual errors would have been very helpful to us trying to diagnose your problem

Comment: You still haven't made it clear what you're trying to do, or answered any of my questions.  It's pretty obvious to me why your existing code is failing, but not what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Your edit is no help, and doesn't answer my questions.  Casting it is a means to an end.  The cast, in and of itself, is ponitless, as you just cast it back to `object` right away anyway.  What are you actually trying to do; why are you trying to cast this to a type not known at compile time?

Comment: @Servy added the method call.  I need to return the items from the cache if it can successfully be casted to the type of the object obj.  Otherwise, I need to remove it from the cache (the catch block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible here you should just use generics, that way you can actually type the returned value to the specified type, and it's pretty easy to check if the object is of that type:

```
public static object Get<T>(DataCache dataCache, string label)
{
    try
    {
        object value = dataCache.Get(label);
        if (value is T)
            return (T)value;
        else
        {
            dataCache.Remove(label);
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (DataCacheException)
    {
        dataCache.Remove(label);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Next, rather than passing in an object of some other type, it would be much clearer for both the implementation of this method, and also for the caller, to pass in a `Type` object that determines what the type of the value should be.  This makes the implementation a bit more work, and it now must return `object` again:

```
public static object Get(DataCache dataCache, string label, Type type)
{
    try
    {
        object value = dataCache.Get(label);
        if (value != null && type.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
            return value;
        else
        {
            dataCache.Remove(label);
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (DataCacheException)
    {
        dataCache.Remove(label);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally we get to the signature you choose, in which you're passing in an instance of some type and you want to ensure that the returned object is of a type assignable to that object's type.  That's doable, but particularly bad practice, so you should almost certainly use the second option instead, if not the first:

```
public static object Get(DataCache dataCache, string label, object typeObject)
{
    try
    {
        Type type = typeObject.GetType();

        object value = dataCache.Get(label);
        if (value != null && type.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
            return value;
        else
        {
            dataCache.Remove(label);
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (DataCacheException)
    {
        dataCache.Remove(label);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is it!  Thank you and sorry it was not easy to understand my intended goal for the method.  Lack of sleep and having tunnel vision is killing my ability to communicate effectively.  I owe you a hug.

Answer (score 2):

You cast object by using (Object).

```
public static object Get(DataCache dataCache, string label, object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                return  (object)dataCache.Get(label);

            }
            catch (DataCacheException)
            {
                dataCache.Remove(label);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to cast it to object.  It already is an object.

Comment: @Servy correct, I need to make sure it matches the type of the obj parameter.

Comment: Of course you don't "need" to in the case above, but you CAN and you might want to do it for other reasons.

Comment: @Dimo What might those reasons be?

Comment: @Dimo But you're not.   You're not casting the object to whatever the type of `obj` is.  You're just casting it to `object`, which is just a noop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue comes from trying to cast your type to `obj` instead of `object`

The good news is, that you shouldn't even have to cast it.

```
    public static object Get(DataCache dataCache, string label, object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            return dataCache.Get(label);
        }
        catch (DataCacheException)
        {
            dataCache.Remove(label);
        }

        return null;
    }
```